# Mark all classes in a specific folder as obsolete

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I am refactoring a large C# project and I need to mark many classes as Obsolete, ie. decorate them with the ObsoleteAttribute. Class files are located into few folders, and all classes from those folders can be marked Obsolete, without exception.

Is there any way I can do it with Visual Studio 2019 without opening all files one by one? I don't know if it helps but I use Resharper as well.

Using a script, some classes are abstract, some are privates, so looking for the class keyword is not enough to find the correct attribute position.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to refactor in that specific of a way using vs2019, but it wouldn't be that difficult to write a script to prepend `[Obsolete]` to all the class definitions.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 ok, I would like to avoid using a script to prevent screwing up all files in case I make a mistake writing it! But, if there is no other solution, how would you tackle it using a script?

Comment: Since you (hopefully!) have all your code in source control, it's no problem if your script messes up the first time. I would go the same route as @TheIncorrigible1 suggests: Write a small script that looks for the start of a class definition (keyword `class` and a bit more) and prepends the `[Obsolete]` attribute. Whether that's something that can be done e. g. by ReSharper I don't know.

Comment: @germi yes for sure, valid point

Comment: Ok, so I edit the question, scripts accepted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick (imo, hacky) approach in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)

```
$script = { Process {
    (@(Get-Content -Path $PSItem.FullName) -replace '(?=.*?\sclass)', '[Obsolete] ') |
        Set-Content -Path $PSItem.FullName
}}

# run from root folder containing files
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *.cs | & $script
```

Parses all the files in the directories for class definitions and injects the attribute at the start of the line containing the keyword.

Comment: Tried using it in the following file, didn't work:
https://ghostbin.co/paste/bpyv5

instead of appending `[Obsolete]` in front of the public keyword, it just add it in between the word `public`

Answer (score 1):

For future people looking to do this easily, you can use Find and Replace to do this in Visual Studios!

1. CTRL+SHIFT+F to open Find and Replace
2. Go to the Replace Tab
3. Type "public class" in the top input
4. Type "[Obsolete("YOUR OBSOLETE MESSAGE HERE")]\n    public class" in second input
5. If you only want to affect one project, change "Look in" to "Current project"